# I want to convert row to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert some value of row to column if they exist multiple time against specific ID

I have one df which have some column like ID and Phone Number. I want to make value of phone number to column if multiple phone number exist against ID

I have this

```
ID  Phone Number
1        234444
1        989898
2         30909
```

I want to do like this

```
ID    Phone Number   Phone Number 2                            
1         234444        989898
2          30909
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pivot your dataframe. Here's one way using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
g = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)
df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns=g).droplevel(0, axis=1).add_prefix('Phone Number ')

      Phone Number 1  Phone Number 2
ID                                
1         234444.0        989898.0
2          30909.0             NaN
```

---

For pandas versions lower than *0.24.0*:

```
g = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)
df_ = df.pivot_table(index = 'ID', columns=g)
df_.columns = df_.columns.droplevel(0)
df_.add_prefix('Phone Number ')

    Phone Number 1  Phone Number 2
ID                                
1         234444.0        989898.0
2          30909.0             NaN
```

Comment: This is giving me an error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'droplevel'

Comment: Thats because its new in verion 0.24.0.. Let me add an alternative

Comment: What pandas version do you have @MalikAsad?

Comment: I am using pandas: 0.19.2

Comment: I think the updated solution should work for your version @MalikAsad

Comment: Not working for me this make a lot of new columns and also change the name of my existing column

Comment: `this make a lot of new columns`? Yes, as many columns as the largest same `ID` group...

Comment: thanks for your time let me find any other solution.

Comment: Nah, not necessarily for aggregating. What about just pivoting a dataframe based on some column, here `ID` @jezrael?

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1','2345'],['1','7890'],['2','1580']], columns = ['ID','Phone Number'])


d2 = df.groupby('ID')
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(d2)):
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, d2.nth(i).add_suffix(i+1)], axis=1) 

new_df = new_df.rename_axis('ID').reset_index()
```

**Output:**

```
print(new_df)
  ID Phone Number1 Phone Number2
0  1          2345          7890
1  2          1580           NaN
```

Comment: Not working for me this make a lot of new columns and also change the name of my existing column

Answer (score 0):

Solutions for pivot one column `Phone Number`:

```
g = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)

df1 = df.set_index([g, 'ID'])['Phone Number'].unstack().add_prefix('Phone Number ')
print (df1)
ID  Phone Number 1  Phone Number 2
1         234444.0         30909.0
2         989898.0             NaN
```

Or:

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)
df1 = df.pivot('idx', 'ID', 'Phone Number').add_prefix('Phone Number ')
print (df1)
ID   Phone Number 1  Phone Number 2
idx                                
1          234444.0         30909.0
2          989898.0             NaN
```

Or:

```
s = df.groupby('ID')['Phone Number'].apply(list)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).add_prefix('Phone Number ')
print (df1)
    Phone Number 0  Phone Number 1
ID                                
1           234444        989898.0
2            30909             NaN
```

Last if need index to column for solutions above:

```
df1 = df1.rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis('ID').reset_index()
print (df1)
   ID  Phone Number 1  Phone Number 2
0   1        234444.0         30909.0
1   2        989898.0             NaN
```

---

Solutions for multiple columns and is necessary process them same way:

```
print (df)
   ID  Phone Number Name  Val
0   1        234444    A   10
1   1        989898    B    4
2   2         30909    C    6

g = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)

df = df.set_index([g, 'ID']).unstack()
df.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.rename_axis('ID').reset_index()
print (df)
   ID  Phone Number1  Phone Number2 Name1 Name2  Val1  Val2
0   1       234444.0        30909.0     A     C  10.0   6.0
1   2       989898.0            NaN     B   NaN   4.0   NaN
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID').agg(list)
comb = [pd.DataFrame(df1[x].values.tolist(), index=df1.index) for x in df1.columns]
df = pd.concat(comb, axis=1, keys=df1.columns)
df.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.rename_axis('ID').reset_index()
print (df)
   ID  Phone Number0  Phone Number1 Name0 Name1  Val0  Val1
0   1         234444       989898.0     A     B    10   4.0
1   2          30909            NaN     C  None     6   NaN
```

Comment: Not sure OP is quite clear on the expected output given his comments on my answer